# Could not find package magento/upgrade-compatibility-tool with stability stable

Tags: magento2, upgrade, compatibility, magento2.4

I am trying to install the Magento Upgrade Compatibility Tool on a Magento Enterprise 2.4.2  version. I am facing below error message while executing the command

```
composer create-project magento/upgrade-compatibility-tool uct --repository https://repo.magento.com
```

Error:

```
[InvalidArgumentException]                                                        
Could not find package magento/upgrade-compatibility-tool with stability stable.
```

[image]

I am following this docs [Upgrade compatibility Tool](https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-operations/upgrade-guide/upgrade-compatibility-tool/use-upgrade-compatibility-tool/run.html?lang=en#download-the-upgrade-compatibility-tool)

My auth keys are already present in the auth.json and it is a enterprise cloud project. Please help.

Comment: find any solution?

Answer (score 1):

I had to check in the below composer path and update the auth keys.

```
cd /home/<user>/.config/composer
```

If you do not find auth.json file than create a file and add the keys.

Comment: but not working any other solution pls

Comment: I am not sure on other solutions. This one worked for me and all the developers I have shared the details with.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to add the debug `-vvv` to the composer run

```
composer create-project magento/upgrade-compatibility-tool uct --repository https://repo.magento.com -vvv
```

After that you will see where is the config file which is loading. So, you will need to add the Adobe commerce authentication to global or local auth.json.